# Who proved first that the Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra of a theory consisting of the propositional tautologies is a free Boolean algebra?

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic

The title says it all: Who first proved/observed that the Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra of a theory consisting of the propositional tautologies is a **free** Boolean algebra? (I don't think it was Lindenbaum or Tarski)

Comment: This is not true. Every Boolean algebra is the Lindenbaum-Tarski algebra of some theory, but not every Boolean algebra is free on some set of generators!

Comment: @AlexKruckman I amended my question, it should be OK now...